# Unable to vote comments on clicking on "^" icon near the avatar of isso commenting system

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am using a commenting system called isso.
https://posativ.org/isso/

```
<script
        data-isso="{{url}}/"
        data-isso-require-author="true"
        data-isso-require-email="true"
        data-isso-css="true"
        data-isso-reply-to-self="true"
        data-isso-vote="true"
        data-isso-vote-levels="[-5,5,15]"
        src="{{ url}}/js/embed.min.js">
      </script>
```

I have set data-isso-vote="true"
However I get the below message,

{"likes": 0, "dislikes": 0, "message": "Upvote denied because a vote has already been registered for this remote address:IP"}
Any idea on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are forwarding the incoming requests to in instance of isso running at localhost, it might be necessary to set the trusted-proxies in the isso.conf file, or else all the votes would appear to come from the same IP. I guess that could be the issue here.